# Can I format my title?

Tags: support, title, formatting

Obviously it's possible in a questions body, but can I somehow format a questions title too?

Comment: Being able to format a title seems to open the door to abuse more than it would be of any help. Better focus on proper wording than formatting to make a title stand out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, titles are plain-text, with a few (slightly annoying for programming-sites) substitutions.

Some other sites on the SE network use MathJax though, and you can do quite a lot with that... which doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Can you please provide details and/or examples of substitutions?

Comment: Well, do you know those dumb smart-quotes? Those are automatically substituted for straight quotes...